# Why does my primes generator return duplicates?

Tags: python, primes

I've written a simple primes list generator for range(3 - 2000). For some reason, the code prints out a bunch of duplicates, and I have no idea why. This is my primes generator:

```
import math

def printprimes():
    count = 3
    Lessthan2000 = True

    while Lessthan2000 == True:
        for x in range(2, int(math.sqrt(count)) + 1):
            if count % x == 0:
                break
            else:
                print count
        if count >= 2000:
            Lessthan2000 = False
        count += 1
```

The resulting printout includes stretches like this:

```
1993
1993
1993
1993
1995
1997
1997
1997
1997
1997
1997
```

What's going on here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`else` clause should belong to `for` instead of `if`

```
for x in range(2, int(math.sqrt(count)) + 1):
    if count % x == 0:
        break
else:
    print count
```

which means `print count` if `for` ends without a `break`.

Comment: I'd discourage this altogether anyway. It's beyond confusing.

Comment: @TobiaTesan do you mean the `for ... else:` construction is confusing? I almost agree except the extra code needed to handle "I have reached the end of the loop without a break" is at least as onerous as the idiomatic `for ... else:` construction. There are worse constructions in Python like "try ... except ... else ... finally" which really tax the mind of [non-Dutch people](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) which I wouldn't let through code review.

Comment: I would suggest an if statement combined with with the any/all functions and a generator / list comprehension. Eg. `if all(count % x != 0 for x in range(...)): print count`

Answer (score 1):

With better names, proper iteration, and a docstring, determining why there are duplicates is easy because there are none.

```
import math

def print_primes(limit):
    """Prints all prime numbers from 3 to limit inclusive.
       This uses a simple algorithm which tests
       each candidate for possible factors.
    """
    for current in range(3, limit + 1):
       for candidate in range(2, int(math.sqrt(current)) + 1):
           if current % candidate == 0:
               break  # current has a factor other than itself
       else:
            print(current)

print_primes(2000)
```

Comment: I started re-factoring (re-writing) this in order to make sense of the OP. When the non-Pythonic stuff was gone, so was the bug.